# Angular - Upload photos in debug, causes site to recompile

Tags: angular, compilation

I have an Angular application where users can upload a profile picture.
The picture is stored at src->media->profileimage

This works fine in prod.

But when I am running Angular in VS Code in debug mode, it automatically recompiles the application every time I do an upload.  Obviously, this breaks the debug session.  This makes sense, because the content of the site has changed.

But how do I set up Angular so it does not do a recompile, every time media content changes?

Comment: out of curiosity, why are storing images in the media folder instead of a cloud service?

Comment: What would be the benefit of using a cloud service when I have a server?  I do have apps that use DropBox and GoogleDrive, but I don't see an advantage to moving profile images out there?

But on top of that, this is on my development machine.